# Best file picker for react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've tried react-native-file-picker, react-native-file-chooser, react-native-document-chooser etc, but none of them are working properly. Can anyone suggest me a good functional file picker for choosing files from device storage?

Comment: These sorts of questions are off-topic on SO because they tend to attract opinionated answer. Please read [ask] for more info.

Comment: ThEsE sOrTs Of QuEsTiOnS aRe OfF-tOpIc On So BeCaUsE tHeY tEnD tO aTtRaCt OpInIoNaTeD aNsWeR. pLeAsE rEaD hOw To AsK fOr MoRe InFo.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On a personal opinion, I use [`react-native-document-picker`](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker).

The [installation](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker#react-native-document-picker) and the [usage](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker#example) is well mentioned in their [docs](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker)

Right now it supports most general use cases required for `file upload`

- All type of Files 'public.allFiles' or
  `DocumentPickerUtil.allFiles()`
- Only PDF 'public.pdf' or `DocumentPickerUtil.pdf()`
- Audio 'public.audio' or `DocumentPickerUtil.audio()`
- Plain Text 'public.plainText' or `DocumentPickerUtil.plainText()`

The rest of the restrictions can be modified based upon your `file type option` as it provides with the following `file res` options

```js
 res.uri,
 res.type, // mime type
 res.fileName,
 res.fileSize
```

Comment: I've already tried it. You have any other suggestions?

Comment: For my `use case` this was the best suited, you may define your `use case`

Comment: And what about photo and video picker support in this lib? As far as I know in iOS it is different framework for picking photo and video.

Comment: Can you also add an example of how it works? I tried with wrapping the DocumentPicker.show() in method in a function that is called when clicking an icon and it doesn't work. It throws an error that DocumentPicker is undefined.

Comment: That error generally means your `DocumentPicker` is not linked correctly, try linking manually as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I am facing the issue on android , executed all the linking steps as mentioned in the docs. see ( https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker/issues/196 ), any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You also need to update `MainApplication.java`. Then clean-rebuild-run

Comment: @PritishVaidya is it possible to pick and get path for emty folder (not a file) with react-native-document-picker?

Comment: @PritishVaidya How we can open document picker UI from our given specific directory? Plz help me out with this.

Comment: I am getting error as > Task :react-native-document-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED 
ain/java/io/github/elyx0/reactnativedocumentpicker/DocumentPickerModule.java:185: error: cannot find symbol

Answer (score 0):

I use react-native-file-picker, because It can select all the files in the phone.
But react-native-document-picker has a very limited selection of files

Comment: The problem with react-native-file-picker is it does not currently work on iOS. They recommend using react-native-document-picker

Comment: @DrorBar But it's not work in ios also :=( I couldn't select any file "not responding"